# Error with Django Class 'City' has no 'objects' member

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and having a blast, I'm trying to build a weather app using Django and the Open Weather API. I seem to have run into an error that's making my head spin and I can't figure it out, I am trying to return a list of all the data in the database but I get this error

> Class 'City' has no 'objects' member"

Here is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is my views.py file

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City
from .forms import CityForm

def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q{}&units=imperial&appid=YOUR_API_KEY'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = CityForm()

    cities = City.objects.all()

    weather_data = []

    for city in cities:

        r = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

        city_weather = {
            'city' : city.name,
            'temperature' : r['main']['temp'],
            'description' : r['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon' : r['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }

        weather_data.append(city_weather)

    context = {'weather_data' : weather_data, 'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'weather/weather.html', context)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add the complete error traceback to the question

Comment: and add the code for CityForm.